# How to display posts from specific category using get_option function?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I try to display posts from specific category only in a author page, using get_option function like in the code below but it does not work:

```
<?php query_posts('cat='.get_option('admin_cat')); ?>
```

However, if using the id number, works perfect.

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=6' ); ?>
```

How can I use get_option function  instead of ID number?

Later edit:
I apologize, it was my mistake that I wrote in admin option the category name instead of its id. 
However a code would be helpful to read both variants, like:

```
if admin option the category is an id
display its id
if in admin option category is a name
display its name
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't see any reason that wouldn't work.  Are you sure `get_option('admin_cat')` returns 6?

Comment: before get_option() please set the value of that option !

Comment: @Hobo, I'm sure that get_option('admin_cat') returns 6. @ Strik3r How can I do that?

Comment: @LiviuCostache: double check. If one works and not the other, it can't be returning 6... Perhaps you're mixing things up with user options, site options, etc.

Comment: @Denis I read somewhere that this function only read ids. Do you know anything about this? Is that true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... `get_option()` returns whatever is stored in the option: id, int, string, array, object, you name it.

Comment: Question edited, sorry about that and thanks anyway.